# I am looking for a python module to colorize the tasks output

Tags: python, colors, output, task

I am looking for a python modulo for a colorized task output format. Anyone know something like that ?
I mean something like:

```
[10:25] Downloading...... [OK]
[10:30] Unpacking........ [FAIL]
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Colorama](https://github.com/tartley/colorama). Works on Windows, too.